# Return exact opposite of array_search

Tags: php, arrays, key

Wondering if there is an easy way to do this...?

I need to search for values that do not exist in an array and return all keys for them.  If the value exists in the array, I don't want the keys for them.  Is there a PHP function set aside for this besides, `in_array()`, since `in_array` would require an `if` statement.  Looking for something that would return an array of ALL keys that do not exist within another array, where the value is not equal to a value.

For example:

```
$array = array('57323' => '23428340', '90234' => '234820345', '29435' => '78283490', '23484' => '213492945');
$value = '78283490';

$arraySearch = array_search($value, $array);

// This would give me $arraySearch = '29435';
```

But I don't want this, I want all, but this!  For example, I would want it to return the following:

`array('57323', '90234', '23484');`

Is there a way to do this quickly and efficiently?

I know I can do this:

```
$anArray = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val)
{
   if ($value != $val)
      $anArray[] = $key;
}
```

But, is there a better way to do this, instead of looping, can I do this on 1 line perhaps?  Is there a PHP function that can be used to do this with perhaps?

Comment: Why don't you just `unset()` the index found by `array_search`, then just get `array_keys`?

Comment: Can't do that because I still need the key that `array_search` finds later on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_diff` in this case. Consider this example:

```
$array = array('57323' => '23428340', '90234' => '234820345', '29435' => '78283490', '23484' => '213492945');
$value = '78283490';

$result = array_diff($array, array($value));
print_r($result);
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [57323] => 23428340
    [90234] => 234820345
    [23484] => 213492945
)
```

Comment: Just used `$result = array_keys(array_diff($array, array($value)));` Cheers :)